# How to find first common occurence in two stacks?

Tags: java, hash, stack

I'm thinking the best route is to just pop off an element from first stack, hash it, then see if the same element in the second stack when popped is in the map. Is this the right track?

Example:

```
stack1 = [1, 3, 4, 1, 2] 

stack2 = [8, 7, 3, 0]
```

the first common occurrence would be 3.

EDIT: I'm going to hash stack1 and then compare each element in stack2 to that hash. Thanks!

Comment: You'd need to move one entire stack over to a hash set first.

Comment: Think carefully about what you mean by "first".  I don't think you've defined the problem precisely enough yet.

Comment: Find the first match (closest to the top) between two stacks.

Comment: @shmosel that's probably the best idea right there. Then just pop one by one off the second list and see if it's in the set. THanks!

Comment: What if the first element of stack1 matches the last element of stack2?

Comment: Hmm. Probably need some conditional statements in there to make sure the match is closest to "top" of stack

Comment: So if one stack is A B C D and the other is C B A D, which is the closest to the top?

Comment: Is it from a homework? Job interview? There is something you forgot to tell us, the solution is probably some kind of trick. Do the stacks consist only of digits?

Comment: It's for a job interview. Assume stacks consist of digits.

Comment: "So if one stack is A B C D and the other is C B A D, which is the closest to the top?"   A and C are closest, so first match would be B

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the logic.  Why is the first match B if A and C are closest?  You really need to define more carefully what you mean by "first match" before you go any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an an array of `boolean` that will represent all the digits, pop each time from one of the stacks, check if the corresponding digit already occurred, if it did you found it if not set it to true:

```
boolean[] digits = new boolean[10];
int digit = stack1.pop();
if (digits[digit]) {
    // found the digit do something with it
} else {
    digits[digit] = true;
}
```

Now do the same with `stack2` and loop until you found it or don't have anything to pop anymore.